# Moving Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to make a screen that 
an image moves to a specific locatiob by clikcing a button.
I found an animation, AnimatedAligned, however this class seems not allow the widget to be located back to the original location.
Any guru knows which animation can be used in this case?

Comment: SlideTransition

Answer (score 1):

Check this out...

```
class SlideTransitionHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SlideTransitionHomeState createState() => _SlideTransitionHomeState();
}

class _SlideTransitionHomeState extends State<SlideTransitionHome>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Tween<Offset> controllerTween = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(1,1));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SlideTransition(
            position: _controller.drive(controllerTween),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.pink,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          _controller.isDismissed ? _controller.forward() : _controller.reverse();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Output:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
If you want it to animate to the center of the top, use this as the tween.

```
  Tween<Offset> controllerTween = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(0,-2.55));
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Is there any function that i can locate the widget to the center of the top?

Comment: Thanks for the update, Josteve. But, can we slide the widget by using Alignment class?

Comment: There’s AnimatedAlign

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can I locate the widget back to the original location using AnimatedAlign?

Comment: Yes use a variable

Comment: could you gimme a little more details,,